# Scaling around median with mirror

Tags: edit-mode, scale

I have a circle with a mirror modifier. When I scale it in object mode, it scales fine, but when I do the same in edit mode, the median seems to be the centre of the non mirrored vertices. How could I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey :). When calculating median in Edit mode, only the original vertices (one side of the circle) are used.

Answer (score 2):

Change the *Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor* (shortcut <kbd>.</kbd>):

[image]